# SQL and SAS programming

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

How do I do the following statement in SQL? I am currently using SAS and cant get it to work many thanks

```
if substr(variable,1,2)='X' then variable='Peter';

else if substr(variable,1,2)='XX' then vairable='Paul';

else variable='UNKNOWN';
```

Comment: Is this in a proc SQL? What specifically are you having issues with? IF translates to CASE, but SUBSTR is the same.

Comment: @Reeza The first substring will never be true because it is selecting two characters and comparing it against a single letter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I noticed, but assumed it's for illustrative purposes. There's also a MySQL tag, so this may not be SAS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UPDATE` statement with a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET variable = CASE WHEN SUBSTR(variable, 1, 1) = 'X'  THEN 'Peter'
                    WHEN SUBSTR(variable, 1, 2) = 'XX' THEN 'Paul'
                    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
               END
```

Comment: Why the UPDATE rather than a PROC SQL?

Comment: I am assuming he wants a query but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
    select *,case when substr(variable,1,2)='X' then 'Peter';
             else when substr(variable,1,2)='XX' then 'Paul';
             else 'UNKNOWN' end as variable 
    from yourfile;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks all got it working with your help.. runs a lot quicker in SQL than my previous SAS data step. Thanks again